# Modeling Forward and Reverse Query Questions in Bigtable

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

Let's say that we have the following three entities:

```
Organization
 - id

Role
 - id

Member
 - id
```

A Role can be granted to a Member within an Organization, thus giving that Member certain access control rights to that Organization. **I'd like to be able to answer the following two queries**:

1. List the IDs of all the members who have a given Role within a given Organization (e.g. given a Role ID and Org ID give me the list of Members).
2. List all of the IDs of the Roles that a member has been granted within a given Organization (e.g. given a Member ID and Org ID give me the list of Roles).

I'm trying to find recommendations on how to model this in Bigtable (ideally with a single row for atomic mutations)... I'm also open to other technology recommendations (I'm trying to design within the constrains my company has given me).

---

If we model the relationship described above using the Bigtable row key `org#{orgID}#role#{roleID}#member#{memberID}`, I can easily answer the first question. However, it doesn't allow me to easily answer the second question. If I duplicate data and store another row key `org#{orgID}#member#{memberID}#role#{roleID}` then I can easily answer the second question, but now I have two rows to manage and atomic updates cannot be guaranteed between the two, so that may lead to consistency issues.

Has anyone in the community ran into a similar problem, and if so, how did you solve it?

Comment: We feed bigtable into bigquery and do the complicated queries from there. There is some automation in GCP that makes this easy. Obviously this doesn't fix the modeling, but saves creating read-views for everything. It might not scale for everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Bigtable doesn't natively support secondary indexes, which is what you would need to only need a single row and be able to efficiently run both of those queries without requiring a full table scan. The alternative to that that you've already identified would be to write two rows via a process that would ensure eventual consistency. This might be sufficient for your needs depending on the underlying requirements of your system.

Depending on your constraints (cloud provider, data scale, atomicity, multi-region replication, etc.), you might be better served with a standard relational database (e.g. Postgres, MySQL), or [Google Cloud Spanner](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/).

Possible approaches with Spanner to accomplish this:

- Have a single table that represents a a Member <-> Role relationship. Have RoleID being the primary index for the row, and then add a [Secondary Index](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/secondary-indexes) for MemberID and you'd be able to run queries against either.
- Go the traditional relational database route of having Member, Role and MemberRole joining table. With Spanner you should have atomic updates via a [Transaction](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/transactions#introduction). When querying you could potentially have issues with reads going across multiple splits, but you'd have to do some real world testing to see what your performance would be like.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have been asked to only use BigTable or Spanner. I've looked into using Cloud Spanner, but I don't see how Spanner would be able to solve the issue. Essentially what I'm looking for is Foreign Key relationships. If I use a swing table relating Members and Roles then I can leverage that swing table to answer both queries. Likewise, I can leverage cascading deletes.

Spanner doesn't support foreign key constraints across tables. Spanner stores this instead using parent-->child tables.

Could you provide an example maybe of what you're talking about with Spanner?

Comment: I'll preface the following with the fact that I am in no way a Cloud Spanner expert. Due to size constraints for comments, I'm just going to edit the answer above.

Answer (score 3):

*Disclosures:*

- I lead product management for Cloud Bigtable.
- I co-founded the [JanusGraph](http://janusgraph.org/) project.

---

Reading through your problem statement, i sounds like you want to use either a relational database, or a graph database. Each one will have its own pros/cons.

### Relational DBMS approach

As Dan mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53732458/3618671), you can use a managed MySQL or PostgreSQL via [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/), or [Google Cloud Spanner](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/), depending on your needs for scale, replication, consistency, compatibility with existing code/frameworks, etc.

### Graph database approach

Alternatively, you can use a [graph database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) which can help you model this information easily and query it efficiently.

For example, you can deploy [Janusgraph on GKE with Bigtable and Elasticsearch](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/running-janusgraph-with-bigtable) and query the data using the [Gremlin language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gremlin_(programming_language)), which is a standard graph traversal/query language supported by many graph databases.

Note that JanusGraph + Bigtable inherits the transactionality of Bigtable (which as you noted, is row-level atomic). Since JanusGraph stores [each vertex in a separate row in Bigtable](https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/data-model.html), only single-vertex updates will be atomic. If you want transactional updates via JanusGraph, you may need to use a [different storage backend](https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/storage-backends.html), e.g.,

- BerkeleyDB (local, non-distributed storage backend)
- [FoundationDB](https://github.com/experoinc/janusgraph-foundationdb) (recent contribution by the JanusGraph community)

There are [many](https://github.com/jbmusso/awesome-graph) [other](https://db-engines.com/en/ranking/graph+dbms) graph databases you can consider, some of which also support Gremlin or other graph query languages. For example, you can deploy [Neo4j on GCP](https://medium.com/neo4j/running-neo4j-on-google-cloud-6592c1b4e4e5) if you prefer, which supports Gremlin as well as Cypher.